# How to keep and reference bilingual glossary in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, translation

In a MediaWiki instance of mine, I found myself using many English terms' Chinese translation repeatedly.

Is there a way to centralize a glossary of such English terms and their Chinese translation such that, in an arbitrary MediaWiki article, primarily written in Chinese, one could display a term's Chinese translation by using some reference that only involves the English term?

That way, i can avoid having to remember the exact Chinese translation, and just specially tag the terms for them to show up translated in the result formatted page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making templates like `Template:English word` with its contents looking like this?

```
中文<noinclude>[[Category:Glossary]]</noinclude>
```

In your wiki pages, write, for example,

```
当前的{{English word}}维基
```

which should result in

> 当前的中文维基

The noinclude portion in the template code is optional, but would allow you to maintain a glossary page at `Category:Glossary` that lists all the English terms. (However, this "glossary" only works in English-Chinese direction, not the other way around.)

Comment: I ended up using this exact solution, i.e. using Template.  The `<noinclude>` trick is good!

Comment: Great! Of course, there could always be better solutions (extension-based, perhaps?), but you're welcome to accept my answer to indicate that this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Translate extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Translate) for your translation work. While translating you will earn a translation memory for free, which will suggest you translations for common phrases next time you encounter them.